# Scrolling a GridView with only Buttons

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView with only Buttons in it. The Buttons should be able to be pressed (working).
But if I want to scroll the gridview with many items in it it is not working on my HTC Desire but it is possible in emulator.

My GridView:

```
<GridView  
  android:id="@+id/gv_control_group" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:isScrollContainer="true" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:numColumns="auto_fit"
  android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
  android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:scrollingCache="true"
/>
```

GridViewItem:

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/gi_socket"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<Button
   android:id="@+id/gi_btn"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:drawableTop="@drawable/green"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Second Question:
How can I make the GridView show more items next to each other when turning the device. Now it just stretches two items to the whole width...

```
android:stretchMode="none"
```

is not working

**edit:**

It's a problem with Android 2.2
In Emulator with 2.1 everything works.
But with Android 2.2 scrolling is not possible anymore ... Is there a workaround to make it scrolling in 2.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved

the problem was that the there was a Button above the GridView, both were in a LinearLayout. The LinearLayout self was in a ScrollView. 
So the ScrollView prevented the GridView from behaving correctly (But not with Android 2.1!)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own `GridView` and override `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` according to what you need, so you can detect if its a move/scroll `event` and leave the `event` in your `GridView` or if it is a click in your buttons pass the `event` to them.

I hope this helps

**EDIT:** regarding your second question, you can use for example:

```
android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="100dip"
```

Comment: thanks, the numColumns problem is gone. But I'm not sure how to implement the functionality in my derived GridView

Comment: check at [this] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) for the documentation regarding this issue. And like it is said in the answer, if its a move `event`, you handle it inside the `GridView`, and if it is a click you pass it to the child.

Comment: i can't get it working... i tried that: @Override `public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent mv){
  if(mv.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
   return true;
  }
  return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(mv);
 }`

Comment: after doing that, whats what you are getting as result? the buttons are not working? or the GridView is not scrolling?

Comment: does the `onInterceptTouchEvent` belong to your `GridView`? if so, also include `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` in the case to return true.

Comment: good, then its intecepting the events... are you implementing a `onTouchEvent` in your `GridView` or in your `Activity`? I cant understand why you are having this problem, I implemented what I suggested for a drag & drop `GridView` that contained some buttons and the scrolling and clicking works fine

Comment: the problem must be somewhere else. even if I always return true in onInterceptTouch the GridView is not scrolling. if I understand it right, then all touchevents must be processed by the gridview

Comment: Yes, you are right, if you don't have any other `touchEvent` manager in your `activity` that is interfering with it, then I can-t think of something else that is causing the problem.

Comment: I tried implementing a GestureListener... It didn't work for the GridView but it works if I use the dispatchTouchEvent method of the Activity but that is a pretty dirty solution. Also I get the Problem that the Views of the GridView don't get drawn... Maybe someone else knows where the difference between Android 2.1 und 2.2 in GridView is and how to slove it. Thanks anyway

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldnt help you further.

Comment: argh... found the problem. look answer below. But thanks for solving my second question!